# TOC entries in Small Caps

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents

I want to have my TOC entries in Small Caps. I cant get by using `\textsc{\tableofcontents}` rather than  `\tableofcontents` but this adds a blank page before TOC. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
% Document Class
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

% Packages
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\scshape\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}


\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\scshape\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{15pt}{\LARGE}


\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\scshape\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{15pt}{\Large}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{Introduction}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]


\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper


\chapter{Second Chapter}

\section{Introduction}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]


\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper


% End Document
\end{document}
```

Comment: This may not work, but try `{\scshape\tableofcontents}` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) and its `\cftXfont` family of commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

% Packages
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\scshape\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}


\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\scshape\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{15pt}{\LARGE}


\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\scshape\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{15pt}{\Large}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\scshape}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{Introduction}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]


\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper


\chapter{Second Chapter}

\section{Introduction}

% Blind Text
\blindtext[1]


\section{Material \& Method}

% Blind Text
\blindmathpaper


% End Document
\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

Notice that `tocloft` was loaded using the titles option:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

so the lists (ToC, LoF and LoT) titles will follow your redefinition using `titlesec`.

Comment: Probably one would also want `\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\normalfont\scshape\huge\bfseries}` in this document, to match all the other chapter titles.

Comment: @Dan No need for that. ALl that is required is to load `tocloft` with the `titles` option (in the exmaple you won't see the difference since the defualt font doesn't provide the boldface smallcaps combination); I edited my answer adding a remark about this.